# XPM "Update Preview" not working

Tags: 2013, experience-manager, session-preview

I am struggling to get XPM preview to work in Tridion 2013, and I am not sure which steps to take exactly to solve this issue.

I can open the Staging website pages in the CMS context (frame). I can edit pages using XPM functionality. I can see items being created in the Preview Session DB. 
But when I select the "Update Preview" button, it says "Loading..." and afterwards I see the exact same page as before, without my changes. I have the web.xml, cd_storage_conf.xml and cd_ambient_conf.xml as per the 2013 documentation.

What steps do I need to take to get to the root cause of this?

Comment: May I suggest updating your question to mention what research you've done to this point. There a few Q&As out there talking specifically to this infamous issue.

Comment: The steps I took were basically following the Tridion 2013 documentation :-) After making various changes I now see the claim processor active in my logs, but when pushing the "Update preview" button, I see that the page filter is looking for the wrong page paths, ie: Uncaught exception thrown by filter Page Content Filter: java.io.FileNotFoundException: SRVE0190E: File not found: /ousel_94ad2f93-db27-408c-81c9-d55f52bece85.js. It seems the /dln characters of our context path is removed from the URLs?

Comment: Got a bit further with this. We are running the XPM staging website as a WAR, AND have a publish location outside of the WAR. So we use the extended document root. It seems we also need to make the different root path known to ADF so file paths are resolved correctly. You need to add your own claims for full_url, real_path, root_path and forwarding using some custom logic like a Java filter. Does anyone have this implemented and can supply me with an example of how to achieve this in Java?

Comment: Was this ever resolved? Is one of the answers below correct or could you post the correct answer?

Answer (score 6):

If you are certain that your dynamic preview content is deployed to your preview database (and your list of steps suggests that you are) you will want to focus on the configuration of your staging web application:

1. wrapper and storage dao bundle configuration in cd_storage_conf
2. cartridges in cd_ambient_conf
3. preview and ambientdata filter in web.xml

You will also want to set all logging to debug level (in logback.xml) and see if any interesting message pops up that can give you a hint in where things are going wrong.

Last but not least it can be very useful to see the currently active claims when troubleshooting Ambient Data issues; there is one going around for .Net but not sure if a java version of the same page (ClaimStore.aspx) exists.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the answer of the steps Experience Manager goes through so that you get a better idea of which modules to troubleshoot:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/10802033/1284894.

The issue is usually due to a bad configuration of the Ambient Data Framework including the Request Filter and cd_ambient_conf.xml, or the cd_storage_conf.xml files on either the application or the web service.

Also, Albert has written a blog about configuring XPM and discusses how to resolved some difficulties when setting it up: http://albertromkes.com/2013/01/24/troubleshooting-the-sdl-tridion-experience-manager-with-session-preview/

Answer (score 4):

You can also verify the configs setting from below link for website, session webservice.

https://code.google.com/p/kickstart-tridion-environment/source/browse/#svn%2FCreateAnEnvironmentForMe%2FCreateAnEnvironmentForMe%2FConfigSamples%253Fstate%253Dclosed

after verifying config, please also verify the JAR files using following link

http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-A4DA06B0-DA5C-4561-BFA9-AECD632674A9 (login required)